How will the force v/s Distance Plot look like for this electromagnet and iron piece pair
Given an electromagnet and iron piece pair with the initial setup as below. Assume that the electromagnet is fixed and the iron piece and move only in vertical direction (lets assume that it is fixed to a vertical rail or something similar):

Now when the electromagnet is switched on the iron piece would move upwards and reach position shown below and stop:

Query: Can someone explain how the force on the iron piece changes w.r.t. to the vertical distance it travels when it moves from initial position to the final position? And why?
I know the exact plot would be too difficult so an approximate plot with a qualitative answer or explanation of why the force change (as it does) would be greatly appreciated.
P.S. I am asking this question the second time as the original simply didn't get any clear answer (I tried to delete it but can't).
Query 2: Has anyone used a software which can provide the calculation of this force with distance (approximation with a few percentage points of error is perfectly fine)?

if your first question didn't get the answers you were hoping for, you need to engage with the answerers you got, not ask it again. If that doesn't yield new understanding: I'm afraid that means your question hasn't been answered to your satisfaction. Don't post it again.

Please see the comments there, I have tried to no avail. the answers are dancing around the Q but not addressing it. Hence the fresh self contained and much clearer Q. If someone has the authority to delete the other one, they should as I haven't got much help there.

no, you just don't seem to be able to understand the answers.

You can try using Flux2D or Flux3D if they din't change "names" ... https://www.epfl.ch/labs/lai/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/ex3A.pdf https://altairengineering.fr/flux/

Or something like this https://solenoid.or.kr/index_dosa_open_2d_eng.html  https://github.com/OpenActuator/DoSA-2D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVtxgqTuSkM

The force increases slightly as the iron piece moves upwards. It increases slightly because the mean magnetic field length is shortening as the iron piece rises. At a point close to the resting equilibrium point, the force rapidly starts decreasing until it is at its lowest value (iron piece at rest).
I know of no software that solves this but, I expect there will be something available.
